# SimpleDateFormat causing unparseable error

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java-13, unparseable

I kinda used the following source to create my own sdf-pattern:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Unfortunately

```
    SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    ...
    private Date getLatestTimeStamp() throws ParseException {
         return mFormatter.parse("Mon, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000");
    }
```

causes the following error and I don't understand why:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000"
```

Any help would be awesome!

EDIT: I am using JDK 13

EDIT 2:

I therefore cleaned up my code, created a new project but it still won't work:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String source = "Thu, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000";
        DateTimeFormatter mFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

       System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(source, mFormatter));
    }
}
```

Following the ful error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000' could not be parsed at index 0
>       at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
>       at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1951)
>       at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
>       at main.java.de.taka.main.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: try SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Comment: Not too sure the cause of your issue but however you code appears to run on repl.it Take a look at [this](https://repl.it/repls/SneakySickDebugging) Also, probably not the cause of your issue but Monday wouldn't be the 19th of december

Comment: see here `2019-dec-19` is `Thursday` but not monday, and also don't use `SimpleDateFormat` you can use newest datetime api from java `OffsetDateTime.parse("Thu, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000",formatter)`

Comment: Thank you very much, but I couldn't fix it. I used your ideas and except Nigels everything worked on repl.it [link](https://repl.it/repls/InsubstantialBackArchive) for more see original post

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. So throw away your first snippet and work on getting the second one to work.

Comment: Related: [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime) (but do prefer the good answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [RFC_1123_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) formatter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "Thu, 19 Dec 2019 11:32:04 +0000";
    DateTimeFormatter mFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;

    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(source, mFormatter));
}
```

By the way, your pattern was good, you should just have added `.withLocale()`.

```
DateTimeFormatter mFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Very good answer. Very good working code and correct explanation of what went wrong in the question.