# What's the correct date format for this case?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I've been trying to parse String into Date, But, The conversion isn't working.

For example, I've these Strings, retrieved from a webservice.

`Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM`
`Jan 12, 2017 11:36:15 AM`

I've tried to use these formats, But, The conversion failed.

`MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa`
`MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a`

Where am I wrong?

I'm getting this exception 
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM"`

Comment: You don't format Strings into Dates - you format Dates into Strings. And you parse Strings into Dates. What exactly do you want to do, formatting or parsing? And what does "the conversion failed" mean - do you get an error? If so, then what's the error message?

Comment: You don't need three `a`s, one is enough.

Comment: And not HH (24 hours) but hh (12 hours) as AM/PM.

Comment: Sorry for expressing myself badly, I would like to parse a string to a date object.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: At this stage, you should stay away from the date types from `java.util` (and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) and stick to `java.time` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a variation of the @C.P.O answer and uses a slightly different pattern.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class blam
{
    private static final String VALUE1 = "Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM";
    private static final String VALUE2 = "Jan 12, 2017 11:36:15 AM";

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;
        LocalDateTime value;

        dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, u h:m:s a");

        value = LocalDateTime.parse(VALUE1, dateTimeFormatter);
        System.out.println("value1. " + VALUE1 + " becomes: " + value);


        value = LocalDateTime.parse(VALUE2, dateTimeFormatter);
        System.out.println("value2. " + VALUE2 + " becomes: " + value);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- y is "year of era"
- u is "year"
- MMM is required.  Neither "M" nor "MM" will work in your case.
- I prefer "s" to "ss" because "s" will parse both 2 and 12, but "ss" will fail to parse "2"

I don't know the real impact of using 'y' instead of 'u'.

Comment: I'm getting this exception ```java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 0```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  I'm running v8.

Comment: I'm running with Java8 too

Comment: The code I show above is correct.  The pattern works for the sample dates you listed.

Comment: As to why it works for DwB and not for Geferson see the linked original question and its answers. Or more precsely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime).

Comment: I was not setting ```Locale.English``` on DateTimeFormatter, doing this, the above code working for me.

Comment: For the impact of usnig `y` instead of `u` see [This question: `uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the time format:

```
String dateString1 = "Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM";
String dateString2 = "Jan 12, 2017 11:36:15 AM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a");

LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, formatter);
LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, formatter);

System.out.println(localDateTime1);
System.out.println(localDateTime2);
```

See the format in this case (time part) is: `h:mm:ss a` (because the hour is 4, not 04), so the format `hh:mm:ss a` will fail

For your inputs, the print will be:
`2016-12-09T16:36`
`2017-01-12T11:36:15`

Comment: Unfortunately is returning ```java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Dec 9, 2016 4:36:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 0```

Comment: @Geferson Usage: it is *throwing* that exception. *Returning* a value is what a (non-void) *method* does when *not* throwing an exception.