# Scala/Java parse date unknown format

Tags: java, scala, date, format

I have the following code:

```
val dateString = "12/Sep/2017:11:25:29 +0200"
println(LocalDateTime.parse(
    dateString, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/LLL/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X")
));
```

and the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '12/Sep/2017:11:25:29 +0200' could not be parsed at index 3
```

What is wrong in my format? I read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html but do not find the correct one

EDIT1: "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X" does not work either

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Answer by Sinigaglia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927956/642706) is correct but insufficient. You should specify a `Locale` for which `Sep` is recognizable as a month name. An English-speaking locale is needed such as `Locale.US`.

If unspecified the JVM’s current default time zone is automatically implicitly applied. `Sep` is not a month name in Russian, French, Japanese, etc.

Tip: As a general rule, always specify explicitly your intended locale and time zone; use the optional arguments. Relying implicitly on the JVM’s current defaults can be problematic.

```
    Locale locale = Locale.US ;
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
    String input = "12/Sep/2017:11:25:29 +0200" ;
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;

    System.out.println( odt ) ;
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Z6jCFK).

> 2017-09-12T11:25:29+02:00

As for your use of `L`, the Javadoc explains that `L` is for the “standalone” month name. Some languages vary the spelling depending on whether the month is used by itself or in combination. English is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `M` instead of `L` (`L` is for the numeric format):

```
"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X"
```

You probably have also to set the `Locale` that java will use to interpret the month (probably your locale is not english)

```
LocalDateTime.parse("12/Sep/2017:11:25:29 +0200", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This works for me (with the locale declared, probably also `L` will work fine)

Comment: maybe OF, but it might help: I use http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/ to test the format of the dates, to check if it's correct or not (is correct if the output of the website is the input that you are providing)

Comment: The doc say the opposite: "   M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J"  and use MMM return the same error

Comment: and I am not sure SimpleDateFormat is equivalent to DateTimeFormatter for text month

Comment: @Benjamin The Javadoc also explains that `L` is for the “standalone” month name. Some languages vary the spelling depending on whether the month is used by itself or in combination. English is not one of those languages.

Comment: @BasilBourque ho OK thanks for the explanation. As I said "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss X" does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Removing `/` from the input String should work. (Didn't check)

`val dateString = "12 Sep 2017:11:25:29 +0200"`

Comment: Why would i need to clean the date before parsing it? / is a well known character in dates formats as far as I know