# Java unable to parse date when using dots "." instead of dashes "-"

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

I have a confusing problem, consider this working code:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    
    Date date = formatter.parse("01-Jan-2017 00:47:13");
    System.out.println(date);
  }
}
```

which prints  `Sun Jan 01 00:47:13 CET 2017` when executing as expected.

However, when I replace each `-` with a `.` dot in the date:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    
    Date date = formatter.parse("01.Jan.2017 00:47:13");
    System.out.println(date);
  }
}
```

The code throws an exception on execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01.Jan.2017 00:47:13"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
    at com.mycompany.mavenproject2.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I am using Java version 12 and German locale.

Has someone got an idea?

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation right, any plain text in the input must match the format string exactly.  There seems to be no either/or operator, nor is there a match-any operator.  For complicated strings you may have to find another class or do the parsing yourself.

Comment: Always use `Locale` with date-time parsing/formatting type. Check [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618676/10819573) to learn more about it. Your code works for me because my default `Locale` supports it. However, I strongly recommend you do it as done in [this solution](https://ideone.com/AndKvv).

Comment: @markspace - but he is expecting a literal dot in the format to match a literal dot in the input.

Comment: Also, note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

Comment: I have reproduced the described behaviour on Java 11 with German locale as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

I strongly agree with the comments recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

Use this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMMuuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
```

Do:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("01.Jan.2017 00:47:13", FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output when run on Java 11 with German locale:

> ```
> 2017-01-01T00:47:13
> ```

You may wonder why compared to your format pattern string I have left out the second dot? On Java 11 (and probably near Java versions too, possibly from Java 9 through 16) German month abbreviations are with a dot to signify abbreviation, so `Jan.` for Januar (January), etc. So in my format `MMM` matches `Jan.` and then `uuuu` matches 2017.

For the fuller story Java gets its locale data including the month abbreviations used in different locales from up to four sources, and not all sources agree what German month abbreviations look like. Since Java 9 the default is `CLDR,COMPAT` meaning that locale data from CLDR, the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository, are preferred. And these include the dots I menitoned. You can get different results by setting the system property `java.locale-providers` to a value that does not begin with `CLDR`.

### What went wrong in your code?

I have given you a hint already: In some Java versions German month abbreviations are with a dot. So in your example with dots as separators your `SimpleDateFormat` matched `dd.MMM` (without the second dot) to `01.Jan.` (with the second dot). According to the format a dot should now come, but since that dot had already been consumed, `SimpleDateFOrmat` looked at `2017`, decided it wasn’t a dot and threw the exception that you saw.

The really surprising behaviour was in your first example where `SimpleDateFormat` was able to parse `01-Jan-2017 00:47:13` without any dots even though it believes that the month abbreviation should end in a dot. I have seen literally hundreds of examples of surprising behaviour of `SimpleDateFormat` before, but never any akin to this one.

And all of these surprises are what make me say: By all means avoid using `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you’re skeptical, I don’t blame you. So to demonstrate:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    
    System.out.println(formatter.format(0L));
    
    System.out.println(formatter.parse("Jan2017"));
    System.out.println(formatter.parse("Jan.2017"));
```

Output, still on Java 11:

> ```
> Jan.1970
> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2017
> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2017
> ```

We see that `SimpleDateFormat` formats the month with a dot, and is able to parse strings both with and without dots.

This still isn’t the full story.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.GERMAN);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(0L));
```

Output:

> ```
> Jan
> ```

This time the month abbreviation was formatted without the dot. I got no idea what is going on. I repeat, forget about the confusing `SimpleDateFormat` class. It’s a notorious troublemaker.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [JDK dateformatter parsing DayOfWeek in German locale, java8 vs java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244724/jdk-dateformatter-parsing-dayofweek-in-german-locale-java8-vs-java9), a question about German locale data from different sources.
- [How to parse month full form string using DateFormat in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219139/how-to-parse-month-full-form-string-using-dateformat-in-java), a question about forgetting to specofy locale for parsing.