# FTL Date Formatting In Netsuite

Tags: datetime, netsuite, freemarker, date-formatting

I have a date coming through as 25/4/2022. I need it changed to 25/APRIL/2022. I have tried every combination of *?date('dd/mm/yyyy') / ?datetime('dd/mmm/yyyy') ?datetime(dd/mm/yyyy)?string('dd/mmm/yyyy')* that I can think of but I keep getting teh same type of errors:

The string doesn't match the expected date/time/date-time format.
The nested reason given follows: Unparseable date: "" ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Java `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern to format dates. If you want the month, use `M` (uppercase), as `m` (lowercase) is minutes in hour. For a full month, use `MMMM`. So, use:

```
${"25/April/2022"?date("dd/MMMM/yyyy")}
```

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_date
- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#topic.dateTimeFormatSettings
- [How to parse month full form string using DateFormat in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219139/how-to-parse-month-full-form-string-using-dateformat-in-java)

Comment: I think 4 `M`s ought to be be enough no? 3+ is text, 4+ is unabridged, but actually using more only makes sense with numbers to specify leading zeros (e.g. `yyyyyy` for `002021`).

Comment: It is one of the examples at the SimpleDateFormat doc. And I've tested it at https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ – although 4 also seems to work.